# how to Update attributes for a given location in java using new API Google mybusiness information

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

Using   [this link: Method: locations.updateAttributes](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations/updateAttributes) , I need to do `updateAttributes` for every location I have in google mybusiness information API.
I cannot find any code example. Would anyone please provide some codes?
Thanks a million

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get that `Attributes` vs `List<Attribute>` might be confusing.
This should help:

```
 public void updateAttributes(String attributePath, List<Attribute> attributes, 
    String attributeMask) {

    UpdateAttributes request = myBusinessBusinessInformation.locations()
        .updateAttributes(attributePath, new Attributes().setAttributes(attributes))
        .setAttributeMask(attributeMask);

       request.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what does attributePath and attributeMask look like?

Comment: attributePath: locations/{locationId}/attributes

Comment: attributeMask: e.g. attributes/has_wheelchair_accessible_entrance

Comment: Would you please also write some examples of setting attributes in different types? for example:  List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
      Attribute attribute=new Attribute(); then I need to do attribute.setValues(values); but the problem is that depending on the type i have various result.